# Creating a Geoserver App-Schema mapping file for GeodesyML

Tags: geoserver, xml, gml, xsd, geoserver-app-schema

EDIT: This appears to be a version dependent issue! When I posted the question I was using Geoserver 2.11.1. I upgraded to the 2.12 nightly SNAPSHOT and I can now general GeodesyML output. The problem I'm currently solving is why my WFS returns a .application file with GeodesyML output that is totally unformatted.

## Background Info:

My question is generally how to construct a mapping file for the GeodesyML schema but I think it will be useful to provide some background since very few people seem to be familiar with GeodesyML. I want to use Geoserver to serve GPS monument metadata from a PostGIS database and output XML according to the GeodesyML schema definition. I have regular GML output working (in a separate Geoserver workspace) so I know my database is accessible and I'm now trying to create the mapping from my database schema to the GeodesyML schema. See links below also.

## Specific Question:

*Why are my mapped features `site_name` to `siteName` and `station_id` to `fourCharacterID` not showing up in my WFS request output and how can I fix it?* I believe my issue lies in my XPath given to  in my mapping file below. I think I am missing something to deal with abstract XML types (most GeodesyML types are abstract) and Geoserver is getting confused. For example when I send a request to Geoserver such as

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=gps_as:GeodesyML&outputFormat=gml32&maxFeatures=3
```

which specifies WFS version 1.1.0 and GML version 3.2 and limits the response to 3 items, I get a response like

```
<wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:gps_as="urn:xml-gov-au:icsm:egeodesy:0.4" 
xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" 
xmlns:gps="http://geoserver.org/gps" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
numberMatched="unknown" numberReturned="3" timeStamp="2017-06-20T19:17:19.347Z" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0 http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd urn:xml-gov-au:icsm:egeodesy:0.4 https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GeoscienceAustralia/GeodesyML/master/schemas/geodesyML.xsd http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2 
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd">
<wfs:member>
<gps_as:GeodesyML gml:id="geoml_monuments.fid--43c4ca2_15cc63f75d5_-7f5a"/>
</wfs:member>
<wfs:member>
<gps_as:GeodesyML gml:id="geoml_monuments.fid--43c4ca2_15cc63f75d5_-7f59"/>
</wfs:member>
<wfs:member>
<gps_as:GeodesyML gml:id="geoml_monuments.fid--43c4ca2_15cc63f75d5_-7f58"/>
</wfs:member>
</wfs:FeatureCollection>
```

## Relevant Links:

Here is the GeodesyML github page, including the .xsd files for GeodesyML: 
http://github.com/GeoscienceAustralia/geodesyml

Here is an interactive schema map for GeodesyML:
http://geoscienceaustralia.github.io/GeodesyML-Github-Pages/

Here is documentation on how to create a mapping file for Geoserver App-Schema:
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/app-schema/mapping-file.html

Here is a tutorial on creating a (very simple) mapping file for GeoSciML:
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/app-schema/tutorial.html

Here is a blog post on making a mapping file for GeoSciML:
http://lab.usgin.org/groups/building-geosciml-wfs-server/ncgmp-geosciml-mappedfeature

## My Mapping File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<as:AppSchemaDataAccess 
xmlns:as="http://www.geotools.org/app-schema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.geotools.org/app-schema AppSchemaDataAccess.xsd">
<namespaces>
    <Namespace>
        <prefix>geo</prefix>
        <uri>urn:xml-gov-au:icsm:egeodesy:0.4</uri>
    </Namespace>
    <Namespace>
        <prefix>gml</prefix>
        <uri>http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2</uri>
    </Namespace>
    <Namespace>
        <prefix>gmd</prefix>
        <uri>http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd</uri>
    </Namespace>
</namespaces>
<includedTypes></includedTypes>
<sourceDataStores>
    <DataStore>
        <id>thedb</id>
        <parameters>
            <Parameter>
                <name>dbtype</name>
                <value>postgisng</value>
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter>
                <name>host</name>
                <value>fakeurl.unavco.org</value>
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter>
                <name>port</name>
                <value>5432</value>
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter>
                <name>database</name>
                <value>fakedb</value>
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter>
                <name>user</name>
                <value>fakeusername</value>
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter>
                <name>passwd</name>
                <value>fakepassword</value>
            </Parameter>
        </parameters>
    </DataStore>
</sourceDataStores>
<catalog></catalog>
<targetTypes>
    <FeatureType>
        <!--<schemaUri>http://localhost/geodesyML_schemas/geodesyML.xsd</schemaUri>-->
        <schemaUri>https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GeoscienceAustralia/GeodesyML/master/schemas/geodesyML.xsd</schemaUri>
    </FeatureType>
</targetTypes>
<typeMappings>
    <FeatureTypeMapping>
        <sourceDataStore>thedb</sourceDataStore>
        <sourceType>geoml_monuments</sourceType>
        <!-- geoml_monuments is a materialized view in the postGIS database and it is used as the source schema, or the schema we are mapping FROM -->
        <targetElement>geo:GeodesyML</targetElement>
        <!-- is the root element of the target schema, GeodesyML -->
        <attributeMappings>
            <!--<AttributeMapping>
                <targetAttribute>geo:GeodesyML</targetAttribute>
                <targetAttributeNode>geo:GeodesyMLPropertyType</targetAttributeNode>
            </AttributeMapping>
            <AttributeMapping>
                <targetAttribute>geo:AbstractSiteLog</targetAttribute>
                <targetAttributeNode>geo:SiteLogType</targetAttributeNode>
            </AttributeMapping>-->
            <AttributeMapping>
                <targetAttribute>geo:siteLog/geo:siteIdentification/geo:siteName</targetAttribute>
                <sourceExpression><OCQL>site_name</OCQL></sourceExpression>
                <encodeIfEmpty>true</encodeIfEmpty>
            </AttributeMapping>
            <AttributeMapping>
                <targetAttribute>geo:siteLog/geo:siteIdentification/geo:fourCharacterID</targetAttribute>
                <sourceExpression><OCQL>station_code</OCQL></sourceExpression>
                <encodeIfEmpty>true</encodeIfEmpty>
            </AttributeMapping>
        </attributeMappings>
    </FeatureTypeMapping>
</typeMappings>
```

Answer (score 3):

I am the technical lead of GA’s effort to adopt GeodesyML. I see that you’ve solved your problem by upgrading to a later version of GeoServer. I would like to suggest a slightly different approach to your mapping and share with you our own implementation of a GeodesyML web feature service, which you may find helpful.

Our interpretation is that `GeodesyML` root element exists for use outside of the OGC/WFS context. Parties may wish to exchange GodesyML documents, by means other than WFS, containing multiple entities, as in the following example:

[MOBS.xml](https://github.com/GeoscienceAustralia/GeodesyML/blob/master/examples/0.4/MOBS.xml)

For your WFS service, perhaps you could consider defining a feature type called `SiteLog` to generate responses of the form:

```
<wfs:member>
    <geo:SiteLog>
        <geo:siteIdentification>
            <geo:fourCharacterId>…</geo:fourCharacterId>
            <geo:siteName>…</geo:siteName>
             …
        </geo:siteIdentification>
    </geo:SiteLog>
     …
</wfs:member>
```

Web feature services can return any XML type that is a subtype of GML `AbstractFeatureType`. This approach would allow you to implement multiple GeodesyML WFS services returning different feature types like `geo:SiteLog`, `geo:Site`, `geo:Setup`, `geo:Node`, which are all top-level entities, in the sense that they are all subtypes of GML `AbstractFeatureType`. Otherwise, I don’t know how would clients of a single feature type called `geo:GeodesyML` specify what information they are interested in. `SiteLog` is just one entity type modelled by GeodesyML.

Here is a link to the data directory of a GeoServer 2.9.1 instance at Geoscience Australia that implements WFS feature type `geo:Site`:

https://github.com/GeoscienceAustralia/Geodesy-Web-Services/tree/next/gws-geoserver/data

This service drives the search screen for our GNSS Site Manager web application, which is currently in development.

Here is a sample query:

```
<wfs:Query typeNames="geo:Site">
    <fes:Or>
        <fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <fes:Literal>true</fes:Literal>
            <fes:Function name="isLike">
                <fes:ValueReference>gml:identifier</fes:ValueReference>
                <fes:Literal>(?i)ad.*</fes:Literal>
            </fes:Function>
        </fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        <fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <fes:Literal>true</fes:Literal>
            <fes:Function name="isLike">
                <fes:ValueReference>gml:name</fes:ValueReference>
                <fes:Literal>(?i).*ad.*</fes:Literal>
            </fes:Function>
        </fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
    </fes:Or>
    <fes:SortBy>
        <fes:SortProperty>
            <fes:ValueReference>gml:identifier</fes:ValueReference>
        </fes:SortProperty>
  </fes:SortBy>
</wfs:Query>
```

and the response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" xmlns:geo="urn:xml-gov-au:icsm:egeodesy:0.4" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" numberMatched="unknown" numberReturned="4" timeStamp="2017-06-21T23:01:54.436Z" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0 http://testgeodesy-geoserver.geodesy.ga.gov.au:80/geoserver/schemas/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd urn:xml-gov-au:icsm:egeodesy:0.4 http://schemas.ga.gov.au/geodesyml/0.4/geodesyML.xsd http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2 http://testgeodesy-geoserver.geodesy.ga.gov.au:80/geoserver/schemas/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd">
   <wfs:member>
      <geo:Site gml:id="Site.852">
         <gml:identifier codeSpace="urn:xml-gov-au:icsm:egeodesy:0.4:SiteIdentifier">ADE1</gml:identifier>
         <gml:name codeSpace="urn:xml-gov-au:icsm:egeodesy:0.4:SiteName">Australia NGA collocated</gml:name>
         <geo:type codeSpace="urn:xml-gov-au:icsm:egeodesy:0.4:SiteType">CORS</geo:type>
      </geo:Site>
   </wfs:member>
   <wfs:member>
      <geo:Site gml:id="Site.895">
         <gml:identifier codeSpace="urn:xml-gov-au:icsm:egeodesy:0.4:SiteIdentifier">QUI3</gml:identifier>
         <gml:name codeSpace="urn:xml-gov-au:icsm:egeodesy:0.4:SiteName">Ecuador NGA colocated</gml:name>
         <geo:type codeSpace="urn:xml-gov-au:icsm:egeodesy:0.4:SiteType">CORS</geo:type>
      </geo:Site>
   </wfs:member>
   <wfs:member>
      <geo:Site gml:id="Site.878">
         <gml:identifier codeSpace="urn:xml-gov-au:icsm:egeodesy:0.4:SiteIdentifier">QUI4</gml:identifier>
         <gml:name codeSpace="urn:xml-gov-au:icsm:egeodesy:0.4:SiteName">Ecuador NGA colocated</gml:name>
         <geo:type codeSpace="urn:xml-gov-au:icsm:egeodesy:0.4:SiteType">CORS</geo:type>
      </geo:Site>
   </wfs:member>
   <wfs:member>
      <geo:Site gml:id="Site.861">
         <gml:identifier codeSpace="urn:xml-gov-au:icsm:egeodesy:0.4:SiteIdentifier">WSRT</gml:identifier>
         <gml:name codeSpace="urn:xml-gov-au:icsm:egeodesy:0.4:SiteName">Westerbork Synthesis Radio Telescope</gml:name>
         <geo:type codeSpace="urn:xml-gov-au:icsm:egeodesy:0.4:SiteType">CORS</geo:type>
      </geo:Site>
   </wfs:member>
</wfs:FeatureCollection>
```

I know that this does not directly answer your question, but instead proposes a slightly different approach, which may side-step your current problem and also be a better way forward. Please let me know what you think.

Comment: Please do not include signatures in your posts as they may be perceived as spam.  Thank you!

Comment: This is really good information on the GA implementation of a GeodesyML mapping. I see that you are defining a custom feature type `geo:SiteLog`. In my approach, instead of defining anything new, I simply used the GeodesyML root element so I can get `<wfs:member><geo:GeodesyML><geo:siteLog>...</geo:siteLog><geo:Site>...</geo:Site></geo:GeodesyML></wfs:member>`

Comment: Lazar, could you please explain further about defining feature types? The example you gave (`geo:Site`) already exists as an element: `geo:GeodesyML/geo:Site`. How would I go about defining a NEW feature type, e.g. `geo:SiteLog` that does not exist as an element? Where would I put the file containing that definition?

Answer (score 0):

Upgraded to Geoserver 2.12 nightly build and it works. Perhaps there is a way to use app schema and GeodesyML in version 2.11.1 but I guess the app schema tutorials use for 2.12 for a reason.

UPDATE: The fix has been backported to the most recent release of Geoserver 2.11.2